# Is unique index/constraint along with NOT NULL keyword technically same as primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Primary key can be clustered or non clustered. It is unique and not null.

Suppose if I create an unique index/constraint and keyword NOT NULL then is this technically the same as primary key?

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate:[Difference between a unique clustered index and a clustered primary key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/149471/140734)

Comment: @Larnu it is related, but this question is not only about clustered indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "technically" the same. The physical index is identical with a primary key, unique constraint, or unique index. A foreign key can reference a unique constraint or unique index as well as a primary key.

Differences that come to mind are:

- Only one primary key is allowed per table
- SQL Server will enforce the NOT NULL requirement for primary key columns but not for unique constraints/indexes
- Unique indexes allow additional options such as `INCLUDE` and `WHERE` clauses, although cannot be referenced by FK constraints when a `WHERE` clause is specified

Comment: In addition to that, unique index can have `INCLUDE` and `WHERE` clauses. Neither of primary / unique constraints AFAIK can have them.

Comment: @RogerWolf, good point, although a unique index with a `WHERE` cannot be referenced by FK constraints. I added that info to my answer.